# Call an object's function via string

Tags: php, function

Please consider the following code:

```
class user{
    public function register(){
    }
}
```

Let's assume that I have two variables: `$class` and `$func`, with the values of `user` and `register` respectively.

How might I call the `register()` function using these two strings as identifiers?

Comment: `register($user,$register)`? I don't understand your question.... please explain further

Comment: You question is very unclear. 2 pieces of string?

Comment: Can you be a little more clear.? Do you want to pass two variables as the arguments for funtion.?

Comment: Unless it's a static function, you need to call `register()` on a `user` object, not the Class itself.

Comment: *How long is a piece of string? Half the length of two pieces of string!* ;o)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're looking for this:

```
class user{
    public static function register() {
        echo 'hi';
    }
}

$cls = 'user';
$fun = 'register';

$cls::$fun();
```

Note that I added "static" there, because otherwise you would need an object:

```
$obj = new $cls;
$obj->$fun();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the function inside the class user with `$this->register();`

And from outside the class using

```
$user = new User();
$user->register();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$reflection = new ReflectionObject('user');

if ($reflection->hasMethod('register')) {
    $object = $reflection->getInstance(); 
    $reflectionMethod = $reflection->getMethod('register');
    $result = $reflectionMethod->invoke($object);                
}
```